# Why Azure IoTHub is defined as Platform as Service?

Tags: azure-iot-hub

I see Azure IoTHub described as Cloud Platform as a Service? could anyone explain why IoTHub is PAAS?

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/services/iot-hub/

From the documentation:
Connect, monitor and manage billions of IoT assets—Use Azure IoT Hub to securely connect, monitor and manage billions of devices to develop Internet of Things (IoT) applications. IoT Hub is an open and flexible cloud **platform as a service** that supports open-source SDKs and multiple protocols.

Comment: Given the question you don't think it is a paas, why not?

Comment: Do we deploy our code in ioTHub? No, so how it is classified as PAAS? sorry but I am failed to understand this.

Comment: No, but IoT Hub gives you the platform to build upon. Code is typically on the device. You don't have to manage the infrastructure of being able to process the messages in the cloud so that why it is called a PaaS solution. Anyway, does it matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To provide some context, the following article gives a high level overview of the various Azure IoT services, both PaaS and SaaS: [Internet of Things (IoT) technologies and solutions: PaaS and SaaS](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/iot-fundamentals/iot-services-and-technologies)